# Generate screenshot without downloading entire video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screenshot

I'm parsing some podcasts in a back-end application and I need to generate some screenshots for them. However, downloading the entire videos is not an option.

Is there a way to download just a small part of the file to extract the screenshot from? Ideally, it would be the middle part.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of Back-end application? A local application? A web app? On what platform? What format are the podcasts in? Where are the podcasts hosted? Why is downloading the video file not an option? Is this supposed to be an automatic or manual process?

Comment: Any type of back-end application. Any platform, preferably Linux. Any format podcasts use (I obviously don't control that). Downloading the video is not an option since they are too large to store them locally on my server. Automatic process.

Answer (score 0):

Is an application that parses xmls to get screenshots in the middle part, on a web app using django and python. I'll hope to be platform independent. It will get podcasts from the place where are hosted and only get the screenshot automatically. The podcasts can have big size (500 Mb) so that's why downloading is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the video hosting server support "Range" http request header which you can find out by seeing the "Accept-Ranges" header value, if it is true then it supports the "Range" header. Then you can ask for the middle 5-10 MB of video using "Range" request header. You can get the content length via "content-length" http response header.